# Android:How to transfer an app from the same app to another Android phone

Tags: android

I am creating an application in Android where i want to transfer my particular app .apk file to another android phone via Bluetooth.
I am setting an option menu called "Share App",on clicking it will transfer my app .apk file to the phone whose Bluetooth is On. 
It worked very well while creating the same app in J2ME,now i am trying it in Android and its not working. So is there any way of doing it??? Any replies will be helpful to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. Is there any other option of Sharing my application to other Android users through my application? I specifically don't want to direct my user to Android Market.

Answer (score 4):

Apps are stored generally in /data/app but you can only access that folder if your phone is rooted.

So AFAIK the only way to do it is maybe to include your apk inside assets folder and then copy it to sdcard before you can share it. But then the received apk cannot be shared because it doesn't have another apk inside assets. So forget about this solution.

The cleanest way would be to direct to user to the market place.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that is possible, an apk can not share itself, however an apk could share a file (which could be another apk) which is packaged into the apk as a resource.

You could also consider doing it the easier way by sharing a link to the Android Market where the other person can install the apk from, or if you don't want to use the market you can share a link to  the apk hosted on a website somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If the application's APK file is available on SD card, it should not fail.

You are just transferring a file (APK or any other) from your SD card to other device via bluetooth. If failed means your code contains bug. So first check your code, it will work definitely.